# Ajax call from Mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile-browser

I have searched a lot but no solution worked for me.

I'm working on a captive portal with pfsense that means a user will need to fill out a form whenever they connect to our network before they recieve free internet. What I'm doing is taking some data from user and making an ajax Get request (using jQuery 3.2.1) to a web service (based on asp.net web api).

Everything works fine when I do it on a computer although it doesn't work on mobile browsers.
I don't know why but somehow data doesn't go to web services when we use mobile phones.

This is my javascript code.

---

```
function uploadData(){      
  var PhNumber = document.getElementById("customerPhone").value;
  var cName = document.getElementById("customerName").value;
  var Url="http://192.168.1.155/customer/api/Values?customerName="+cName+"&customerPhone="+PhNumber+"";
  var exp = /^((\+92)|(92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$/;
  var cNum = exp.test(PhNumber);



if (exp.test(PhNumber)) {

    $(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url : Url,                    
                cache : 'false',
                dataType:'xml',                                     

                success: function (responce) {
                    return alert("Data Saved");
                },
                failure: function() {
                    alert("Some Error Acured");
                }
             });
        });                      
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi are you sure the format is xml ? ..and then have you activated the CORS on your back end ??

Comment: could be a number of things. Does 192.168.1.155 accept incoming connections? Does it work on a different computer than the development computer?

Comment: Yes, I have tested 192.168.1.155 from more then one computers and its working fine on all of them ,  only problem is with mobile phone browsers.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I have tried with text, json , jsonp and xml works all format works well on pc but not on phone.

Comment: mmm can you console.log(error) form the request?

Comment: Have you tried it with both iOS and Android? Could be specific to one mobile OS

Comment: You can try debugging with port forwarding option available in Chrome by connecting the mobile.

Comment: On remote debugging i found this error on console No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource while I have enabled cors on web Api and its also working fine on computer browsers but not on mobile phones.